# Derivative of an exponentially weighted moving average

Tags: calculus, statistics, regression

It has been a while since my university math courses, so let me apologize right off the bat...

I'm using GSL to perform non-linear regression analysis and am mostly happy with the outcome, however, my covariance matrix is not looking right and I suspect that I have not calculated the derivative of my equation properly.

The equation in question is as follows:

$$
y(t) = k_1*g(t) - k_2*h(t)
$$
$$
g(t) = g(t-1)*e^{-1/tau_1}+l_t
$$
$$
h(t) = h(t-1)*e^{-1/tau_2}+l_t
$$

The best I've come up with in terms of the derivatives are as follows:
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial k_1} =g(t) = g(t-1)*e^{-1/tau_1}+l_t
$$
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial k_2} = -h(t) = -h(t-1)*e^{-1/tau_2}+l_t
$$
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial tau_1} = \frac{k_1*g(t-1)*e^{-1/tau_1}}{tau_1^2}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial tau_2} = -\frac{k_2*h(t-1)*e^{-1/tau_2}}{tau_2^2}
$$

However, I suspect these derivatives are incorrect and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Is $g(t-1)$ independent of $\tau_1$?

Comment: Thanks Chinny84. I believe $g(t - 1)$ is not independent of $tau_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that $g(t) = e^{-\tau_1} g(t-1) + l_t$ is a delay equation, the solution of which is 
$$
g(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{\tau_1}} \left( \lfloor t \rfloor f(t - \lfloor t \rfloor)
+ \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor t \rfloor} l_{m+t-\lfloor t \rfloor } e^{\frac{\lfloor t \rfloor}{\tau_1}} \right)
$$
with f(t) an arbitrary function on $[0,1)$,
and similarly for $h(t)$. Although you could differentiate this expression with respect to $\tau_1$ (and your expression does not get that answer), this extra function degree of freedom will cause you grief unless you apply some conditions (such as analyticity and/or some initial conditions) that fix $f(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mark. I've spent a couple days thinking about it and am struggling with the form initial conditions might take. I do know, for example, that $tau_1 > tau_2$, $k_2 > k_1$, $0 < k_1 < 1$, $0 < k_2 < 1$, and both $tau_1 > 0$ and $tau_2 > 0$. While these are conditions, I'm not quite sure how they would improve the differential. Can you point me a little further in the right direction? Thanks in advance.